# How to open custom post type in popup window instead of page

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, custom-post-type

I want to show custom post type to show in a popup window instead of opening another page for a post, I have this code in my functions.php, I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and figured it was about time to reach out to the community.

```
function our_artist(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Artists',
        'singular_name' => 'Artist',
        'add_new' => 'Add Item',
        'all_item' => 'All Item',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_iten' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'search_item' => 'Search',
        'not_found' => 'No Items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item'
    );    
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt'
        ),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
    register_post_type('artists',$args);    
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'our_artist');
function arc_create_artist_cat_tax_rewrite() {
    register_taxonomy('artist_cat',array('artists'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => 'Artist Category',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'artist_cat' ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'arc_create_artist_cat_tax_rewrite', 0 );
```

Comment: you cannot set this when creating the post type, this is done by setting the `target` attribute of the html `a` tag. example `<a href="example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a>`. It depends on the browser setting if it opens in a popup or new tab doing it this way. There are also other ways of making a popup using javascript

Comment: You have created a custom post type. Now where would that appear? The popup needs to appear in some page right? And how are you going to determine which post of this particular post type you are going to pick?

Comment: I would like for the read more button on post to pop open a lightbox window that shows the featured image and content. I prefer it not go to another post page, and I'm using  a plugin shortcode to show these post on page https://arcproject.thenoah.net/break-room/ this is the page I'm working on

Comment: The behavior of the page and whether something opens in a new page or a lightbox is a concern of the front-end. Because of that, you will need to modify the theme or add a plugin to add the behavior you want. Once your custom post type is set up, you should be able to modify the theme code to check for that post type and add the behavior you're looking for either using JavaScript to handle lightbox behavior or the target blank example mentioned by @JasperB above.

Comment: If you want the Read more to open the post, why are we looking at how to create a custom post type. Do you know how to display this custom post in a page before you want to put it in a popup?

Comment: i asked (How to open custom post type in popup window), I never mentioned how to create CPT. @MariaNirmal

Comment: Why have you shared this code here?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
<?php if('artists' == get_post_type()){ ?>
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a>
<?php }else{?>
    <a  href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a>
<?php }?>
```